# Can anyone help me with this Apple Mach-O Linker Error?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone, chipmunk

I know this is not a programming question, and I need help with setting up Chipmunk. I have already wasted half a day on this and tried solutions from other similar postings...

But can anyone help me with the following errors ?

[image]

Comment: Where are the functions cpSpace* declared/defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue resolved with just initializing a project under chipmunk. I had write/copy all the methods from my previous class, and it took some time to do that... but it was worth it in the end !

Answer (score 1):

You're not linking against the library that contains `cpSpaceStep`, `cpInitChipmunk` or `cpSpaceNew`. It looks like that is cocos2d. Make sure you've got the cocos2d library added to your project and that it is part of the "Link binary with libraries" build phase.

Comment: I believe every things added properly ! :(

Comment: Try removing it and adding it again like @iamsult says. Also, check that the cocos2d library actually has support for the simulator in it or that you've got the right library which includes simulator support. I don't know anything about cocos2d other than that it exists so don't know the ins and outs of how to use it. If you're still stuck I suggest asking on cocos2d forums.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the library and add once again. I have faced this issues couple of times.
Hope this helps.